# Does VPC provide any benefits if I am only using RDS and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have my web service running on a proprietary VM (Azure) instead of EC2 instance. But I am still using Amazon's RDS and S3 to store data and serve static and media files. In my case, is there any benefit in using VPC? From my understanding two benefits are security and network performance. Will I still be able to take advantage of it (even slightly)?

Comment: if I get another downvote, I will take that as no.

Comment: I'm not going to dv, but honestly, with your application and DB tiers is separate cloud providers, you have much larger issues to sort out than worrying whether or not you should use VPC (which you should).

Comment: @EEAA could you please elaborate a bit? Even one problem or a link to describe cons of such setup would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Your app has to query your database via the public internet. Not only is this likely insecure, but also its subject to wildly variable latency. Choose I've provider and host all of your stack with them. Once you've done that, then you can allow yourself the luxury of tweaking things for performance.

Answer (score 5):

VPC is the new standard:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html

You should use the standard.